# Graph from shapefile Python

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, shapefile

I'm working on old French Napoleonian cadastre, I've vectorized it, and now I've been studying parcels' neighborhood relation. I want to know which polygon is next to which polygon.

I tried NetworkX python library, but I did not succeed to convert my shapefile to a graph. I want to extract centroids from my polygons and trace relation between them.

I can use line shapefile or area shapefile to represent my parcels.

There is my python code:

```
import networkx as nx

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.read_shp('path/to/shp') #Read shapefile as graph

pos = {xy: xy for xy in G.nodes()}

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,node_size=10,node_color='r')

nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edge_color='b')

plt.show()
```

This is my shapefile:
[image: This is my shapefile]

Answer (score 0):

All right, I've fixed my problem with PySal library.

There is my code if someone need to generate some graphs!

```
##Définition des relations d'adjacence

qW = ps.queen_from_shapefile(str(planche)+".shp")
dataframe = ps.pdio.read_files(str(planche)+".shp")

## Affiche la matrice de voisinage complète.

Wmatrix, ids = qW.full() #ou ps.full(qW)
print("Matrice d'adjacence complète:\n", Wmatrix)
print("\n")

## pour compter le nombre de voisins que possède une parcelle:

n_neighbors = Wmatrix.sum(axis=1)

for i in range (len(n_neighbors)):

    if n_neighbors[i] != 0:
        print("La parcelle %i a %i voisins" %(i,n_neighbors[i]))
    else:
        print("La parcelle %i n'a pas de voisin" %i)

print("")

## Affiche [parcelle choisie, ses voisins]:

for i in range (len(n_neighbors)):
    self_and_neighbors = [i]
    self_and_neighbors.extend(qW.neighbors[i])

    if self_and_neighbors[1:] == []:
        print("La parcelle %i n'a pas de voisin" %i)
    else:
        print("Les voisins de la parcelle %i sont les parcelles " %i, self_and_neighbors[1:])



##Extractions des coordonnées des centroïds:

centroids = np.array([list(poly.centroid) for poly in dataframe.geometry])


plt.plot(centroids[:,0], centroids[:,1],'.')
for k,neighs in qW.neighbors.items():
    #print(k,neighs)
    #origin = centroids[k]

    for neigh in neighs:
        segment = centroids[[k,neigh]]
        plt.plot(segment[:,0], segment[:,1], '-')

##Affichage des numéros des centroïds sur le graph:

for i in range (len(centroids)):
    plt.text(centroids[i][0],centroids[i][1],str(i))

plt.title('Graph de la planche '+str(planche)+ " de l'année "+str(annee))
print("\nDuree: %.2f sec" %(time.time()-deb))
show()
```